# What is the usage of DummyOperator in Airflow?

Tags: airflow

I 'm new to Airflow and I know DummyOperator just does nothing. 
So what is the scenario for DummyOperator?
When would you typically use it?

Comment: People, this is a perfectly valid question, not too broad in the context of Airflow. If you don't know what the topic is about, please don't vote to close questions. Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A common use is to create simplified workflows. Consider an example.

```
task_1 >> task_3
task_2 >> task_3
task_1 >> task_4
task_2 >> task_4
```

Technically you want `task_3` and `task_4` to be executed only after both `task_1` and `task_2` are completed. But when you look at the graph, it is not super intuitive.

Solution? You can improve the readability (not code readability instead you can understand the graphs and thereby workflow.) by adding a `task_dummy` after `task_1` and `task_2` and run `task_3` and `task_4` after `task_dummy`. So when a new user takes a look at graphs, he will immediately understand the workflow. The modified workflow will be as follows.

```
task_1 >> task_dummy << task_2
task_dummy >> task_3
task_dummy >> task_4
```